# MEAN stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token f" Comments not posting

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mean-stack

I am working on a blog where you can answer a question and people can comment on the answer. Asking and answering the question works fine. But posting a comment does not. 
After investigating I know its JSON related. Probably dealing with body-parser in some way. Maybe I'm wrong. Have spent hours comparing code and can't find where the error is. Here is the error and the console.log:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/answers/5807c9ef24adc7ea591a35b1/comments/ 400 (Bad Request)

Object {data: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token f<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;a… &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)↵", status: 400, config: Object, statusText: "Bad Request"}
config
:
Object
data
:
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token f<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\US\Documents\coding\KelvinDashDemo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\US\Documents\coding\KelvinDashDemo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\US\Documents\coding\KelvinDashDemo\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\US\Documents\coding\KelvinDashDemo\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\US\Documents\coding\KelvinDashDemo\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at emitNone (events.js:67:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)↵"
headers
:
(d)
status
:
400
statusText
:
"Bad Request"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Here is my app.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');


//App init
var app = express();
require('./server/config/mongoose.js');

var sessionConfig = {
 secret:'CookieMonster', // Secret name for decoding secret and such
 resave:false, // Don't resave session if no changes were made
 saveUninitialized: true, // Don't save session if there was nothing initialized
 name:'myCookie', // Sets a custom cookie name
 cookie: {
  secure: false, // This need to be true, but only on HTTPS
  httpOnly:false, // Forces cookies to only be used over http
  maxAge: 3600000
 }
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}));
app.use(expressSession(sessionConfig));
```

My client side commentFactory:

```js
kelvindashdemo.factory('CommentFactory', ['$http', function($http){
 var factory = {};
 factory.createComment = function(comment, topicId, callback){
  $http({
   method:"POST",
   url:"/answers/"+topicId+"/comments/",
   data:comment
  }).then(function success(){
   callback();
  }, function failure(res){
   console.log(res);
  }) 
 }
    factory.dislike = function(id,callback){
 $http({
  method:"GET",
  url:"/comments/dislike/"+id
 }).then(function success(){
  callback();
 }, function failure(res){
  console.log(res);
 })   
}
factory.like = function(id,callback){
 $http({
  method:"GET",
  url:"/comments/like/"+id
 }).then(function success(){
  callback();
 }, function failure(res){
  console.log(res);
 })   
}
return factory;
}]);
```

My server side commentController:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Answer = mongoose.model('Answer');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

module.exports = {
 createNew: function(req, res){
  console.log("HERE");
  var commentInfo = req.body;
  commentInfo._author = req.session.user;
  commentInfo._answer = req.params.id;
  var comment = new Comment(commentInfo);
  comment.save(function(err, comment){
   User.update({_id:req.session.user}, {$push:{comments:comment}}, function(err, user){  //pushes comment into user db with id
    Answer.update({_id:req.params.id}, {$push:{comments:comment}}, function(err, comment){ //pushes comment into topic db with id
     if (!err){
      res.sendStatus(200);
     }else{
      res.sendStatus(400);   //can also be a 500 error msg
     }
    });
   });
  })
 },
```

And lastly my server side comment model:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 comment: {type:String, required:true}, 
 _answer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required:true, ref: 'Answer'},
 likes: {type:Number, default:0},
 dislikes: {type:Number, default:0},
 _author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required:true, ref: 'User'},
}, {timestamps:true});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

ADDED in my topicController for reference:

```js
kelvindashdemo.controller('topicsController', ['$scope', 'TopicFactory', '$location', '$routeParams', 'AnswerFactory', 'CommentFactory', function($scope, TopicFactory, $location, $routeParams, AnswerFactory, CommentFactory){
 TopicFactory.getTopic($routeParams.id, function(topic){  
  $scope.topic = topic;
  console.log(topic);
 })
 $scope.postAnswer = function(answer, topicId){      AnswerFactory.createAnswer(answer, topicId, function(){    TopicFactory.getTopic($routeParams.id, function(topic){  
    $scope.topic = topic;
    $scope.answer = {};
    console.log(topic);
   })
  })
 }
 $scope.postComment = function(comment, answerId){   
  CommentFactory.createComment(Comment, answerId, function(){   
   TopicFactory.getTopic($routeParams.id, function(topic){   
    $scope.topic = topic;
    console.log(topic);   
   })
  })
 }
 $scope.like = function(id){
  CommentFactory.like(id, function(){   
   TopicFactory.getTopic($routeParams.id, function(topic){  
    $scope.topic = topic;
    console.log(topic);
   })
  })
 }
 $scope.dislike = function(id){
  CommentFactory.dislike(id, function(){   
   TopicFactory.getTopic($routeParams.id, function(topic){  
    $scope.topic = topic;
    console.log(topic);
   })
  })
 }
}])
```

Any and all feedback is welcome. I look forward to hearing its a missing comma somewhere.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but check this line:
`_author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required:true, ref: 'User'},}`

Not sure you need the comma there. 

Also never seeing a closed ']' from this line: `kelvindashdemo.factory('CommentFactory', ['$http', function($http){`

Comment: I'd check what the HTTP request looks like in the network tab of your developer tools; most likely, valid JSON is not being sent.

Comment: What are you passing to `createComment`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added the entire CommentFactory Riccardo. Unfortunately, I beleive I do have the missing closing ]. Referring to the comma in the comment model... i checked my other models and I have one in the exact same place. I don't have any issues with any other model.

Comment: Jacob, I added the topicFactory so you can see what I am passing to the CommentFactory. I checked the network tab and the only red indicator is the answer/id/comment line. Looking at the Header i see this the request header accepting 'application/json, text/plain' but nothing stands out as 'bad json being passed'. There is also the Request Payload which has "function Comment() {[native code]}". Really not sure what I should be looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `createComment`:

```
$scope.postComment = function(comment, answerId) {
  CommentFactory.createComment(Comment, answerId, function(){           
    TopicFactory.getTopic($routeParams.id, function(topic){         
      $scope.topic = topic;
      console.log(topic);           
    })
  })
}
```

...you're passing `Comment`, which isn't defined in any of the code you've posted, but I'm guessing it is a constructor function of some sort. Within that function:

```
factory.createComment = function(comment, topicId, callback){
    $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"/answers/"+topicId+"/comments/",
        data:comment
    }).then(function success(){
        callback();
    }, function failure(res){
        console.log(res);
    })  
}
```

...the first argument is sent as the data to `$http`. If `Comment` is a function, not an object that can be serialized to JSON, it is getting converted to the string `function Comment() {[native code]}`, which would blow up the JSON parser on the server (notice it's complaining about encountering the `f` character).

I *think* what you meant to do is to pass `comment`, not `Comment` when calling `CommentFactory.createComment`:

```
$scope.postComment = function(comment, answerId) {
  CommentFactory.createComment(comment, answerId, function(){           
    TopicFactory.getTopic($routeParams.id, function(topic){         
      $scope.topic = topic;
      console.log(topic);           
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Jacob, thank you. That was it. I've walked down and back that path so many times... should have caught that. I owe you a drink sir. Take care.        PS.. I upvoted this but since I'm new its not going to record it until other do.

Comment: No problem. It's a pleasure when someone provides such helpful amounts of detail.